# What is the less symbol sign in snort content

Tags: snort

For example in snort, there might be content like

- content:"|C0 0C 00 0C 00 10 00 00 00 00| < |OO OF|"

May I know what is the meaning of "<" between two hex values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The characters between pipes `|` represent hexedecimal bytes, the '<' is just a literal '<' character with no special meaning.

Many times rule authors will chose to represent printable ascii characters where possible in order to make the content match more readable. In this case, I'm not sure it helps.

Comment: Hi ohthatgeoff,  thank you so much for the answer, I'll confirm it later. Thanks!!!